# BS4 find_all (recursive=False) seems to dredge deep

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I seem to have found a question that is stumping me at the moment. I want to process only the first *tier/level* <p> tags after the <body> tag. But the BS4 find_all (recursive=**False**) seem to be dredging up all the <p> tags embedded deeper in the tree. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4

my_html = '''
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    <p>
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Should not match</p>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h2>headline</h2>
        <p>Should not match</p>
        
    </p>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
'''

tree = BS4(myhtml,'lxml')

body = tree.find('body')
all_p = body.find_all('p',recursive=False) # recursion is set to False
for element in all_p:
    if (element.parent == body): #tried to ensure the parent is body element
        if (element.name=='p'):
            print(element.text)

print(len(all_p)) #should return 1
```

Results in:

> Should not match
> Should not match
> 5

[Edit]
Expected Output

> ("Should not match") should not be printed 
> 1 (there is only 1 child of "P" under "body")

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: "Shoud not match" should not be printed. And the len(all_p) should be int(1)

Comment: use `find` then and you don't need to use `find_all` which return a list! also `recursive` has nothing to do here since you are picking up the original parent of all internal `p`, also you can practice here https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: hmm..  thanks for the suggestion but I need to get a list of P element tags (not just the first instance) but I don't want to get the descendent P's. The only way I can think of is to fall back to lxml and use xpath to get specific structures but I would like to remain consistent and use BS4 for continuity and code readability.

Comment: then, [edit] your question and include the expected output itself. other than the length, i would need to see actual output

Comment: Your HTML code is **Invalid**. You cannot have a ```<p>``` inside another ```<p>```. Please fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! (DOCTYPE is HTML 4.01 Strict)... dang.. will close this then and go further upstream to look at the data generator

Answer (score 0):

Closing this as the data is invalid - DOCTYPE is HTML 4.01 Strict does not allow for nested P tags. Will chase the issue further upstream (data generation).